# Edit Tooltip of Slider in XAML

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

Edit Tooltip design for Slider Control in WinRT XAML, [Please click for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHYx3.png)Is it possible to make the tooltip always visible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to change the slider's default behavior. You could consider showing the current value some other way, with a label or other visual.

For example:

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=slider,Path=Value}"></TextBlock>
    <Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="100"></Slider>
</StackPanel>
```